# Can I generate llvm IR compatible with an older llvm version with clang?

Tags: c++, c, linux, llvm, clang

On my system I have clang 2.9 but llvm 2.8. Is there any way I can instruct my clang 2.9 compiler to generate an IR (with flag -emit-llvm) compatible with llvm 2.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. While stuff in other way generally works (IR from 2.8 will be auto-upgraded when read into 2.9), there is no way you can generate IR for lower version of LLVM.

Also, both 2.9 and even more 2.8 are ancient :)